Migrate ASP.NET Core Vue to stand alone Vue.js project
I'm not very familiar with Vue.JS, I have a project in ASP.NET Core with Vue that has an API and a client app. I'm trying to separate them. I was able to separate the API part and that is working.
However, I'm having an issue with the Vue.JS app. Initially I just copied the built files in the ClientApp/dist folder. However, I don't think that's the right way because you can't really edit it. I have mostly copied the information in the src folder with services, views and router. But I'm not sure which file will be my main JS files and entry HTML files.
Is there a step by step guide somewhere or what are the steps required to make the client app work independently? This vue.JS app I want it to be standalone and calling the API separately.
Any help, links will be appreciated.

Hi @Aman, you can firstly create a vue.js project. Refer to:Create a Vue.js app. Then copy the relevant parts of your existing Vue.js app (components, views, router, store, etc.) into the new project structure.

As @Rena said, the straightforward way is to create a fresh Vue.js project and copy the src files and directories into the new project, as well as adjust other existing files such as main.js and index.html  to meet the new Vue.js project requirements (Router, stores, etc). To avoid common errors, tune the package.json file before copying; the packages in both files match the version.
